# PowerShell-when are variables loaded and cleared?

Tags: powershell

I come from programming background (C#, VB) but I am relatively new at PowerShell.

I usually develop my scripts in Windows PowerShell ISE

```powershell
Function Calculate-Area {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter()]
        [int] $Length,
        [parameter()]
        [int] $Width

    )
    Return  $Length * $Width
}


 CLS
 $Area = Calculate-AreaValue -Length 12 -Width 10
 $Area
```

My main question is if I run the script, I receive the output I would expect. If I run it, a second time and say I have an error in my function, $Area still has the value from the first run, why?

My second question is similar. Earlier I could not work out why my script was failing when I renamed the function (I am actually working on a more complicated script involving active directory). I have since realised that you need to declare the function before you call it (I had the function at the bottom of my script). Therefore when the function was at the bottom of my script, it would return with an error the first time I ran it but would be successful the second time. So like the variable, why is PowerShell remembering values/functions from previous runs?

Thanks

Comment: If you ran the function successfully the first time, the variable was loaded with the returned value via the success stream. Since variables aren't cleared until after the session is closed (*except those stored in persistent storage*), if it's not overwritten, if it's not removed via `Remove-Variable`, or if it's not scoped, the persistence of a variable depends on its scope and where it was created. As for why it didn't load the error into the variable, it's due to how PowerShell handles it's different data streams where **errors** aren't a part of the success stream that get written to it.

Comment: Since PowerShell isn't a compiled language, but rather an interpreted one, you have to load the functions into memory before calling them as it has no idea what they are if it's not directly associated to a file where it's being executed from.

Comment: I don't think you can compare the other languages (as C# and VB), simply because they don't have a similar [expression mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing#expression-mode).

Comment: Like Windows PowerShell, I am not sure if ISE is getting any further development. Proabably good to upgrade to VS Code for a better development/debugging environment. https://code.visualstudio.com/download